# Added a link in-app for external site. Despite submitting to App Store, it's consistently rejected

Tags: ios, react-native

[When I submit the application to the App Store, it consistently results in rejection. I am seeking a more effective solution for this issue.could you provide guidance on this matter?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NmpB.jpg)

[Additionally, I am interested in implementing an App Store confirmation popup that appears when users click a link within the app. The desired format for this popup is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01XDy.jpg)

Comment: You aren't Netflix. You aren't going to be permitted to link out to your website for payment. You need to follow Apple's instructions shown in the first image. Remove all references to payment outside of in app purchase.